# How to visualize list of event parameters and their count in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm setting up a Dashboard in Google Data Studio where I would like to show the top event parameters in a table but I'm struggling to understand how to configure such a query.

**Context**
We are using Firebase Analytics in our app to post built in and some custom events about what the users are interacting with in the app. In this particular case, we are logging the built-in 'select_content' event (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events#select_content) where we pass in content_type and item_id of the type of content you clicked on, as well as a unique identifier of the item you clicked.

As an example, let's say we're logging different types of groceries and the grocery you selected (content_type: 'fruit', item_id: 'apples'). I would then like to create a table in Data Studio that lists let's say the top 50 groceries that have been interacted with and the number of times that those groceries have been clicked on.

I cannot for the life of me understand how I would set up such a table in Data Studio even though to me it sounds like one of the most basic things I would want to do. I've tried creating tables with different combinations of dimensions, metrics and sorting on the table but can never get anything but a counter that shows the aggregate of that event type is registered (which is not what I want). The exact table that I want is showing up perfectly fine if I go to Google Analytics -> Life Cycle -> Engagement -> Events -> and click on the 'select_content' event, see screenshot below.
[image: GA Item ID]

Anyone got any idea or link that they can provide to shine some light onto this?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue trying to bring parameter data into Google Data Studio. Here's what worked for me:

1. Create a custom dimension in GA4

Configure -> Custom Definitions -> Create custom dimensions
Name = Item ID
Scope = Event
Description = Optional text to identify your dimension
Event parameter = item_id

2. Refresh Google Data Studio

Give it 24-48 hours. Then open your Data Studio report. 
Resource menu -> Manage added data sources 
Under the Actions header, click Edit next to your GA4 source.
At the bottom, click Refresh Fields.
You should see your Item ID custom dimension appear as a new field available in the report.